# Group pandas rows by ID, create new columns for time entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe, which has duplicate IDs since each row represents a measure of time.

```
 pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 6], [2,7]], columns=['id', 'colA'])
```

I want to transform it in a way that each row represents one ID, and the time series aspect of the data is captured in new columns. I.e: I want to output to look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,6,7]],columns=["id","colA_0","colA_1"])
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id', df.groupby('id').cumcount()])['colA']
         .unstack()
         .add_prefix('colA_')
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   id  colA_0  colA_1
0   1       2       3
1   2       6       7
```